# Prove that function is not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

I have to prove that the function $$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array} \\ x^2 \cos\frac{1}{x},& x\neq 0\\ 0,& x=0 \end{array} \right.$$
is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and I just can't find the two sequences to do that.

Any ideas which ones I should use?

Comment: If you want to show that $x \mapsto x^2$ is not uniformly continuous, how do you do that?

Comment: @DanielFischer I'd use the sequences $x_n =\sqrt{n}$ and $y_n=\sqrt{n+1}$

Comment: What about using the sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ with $n>0$ integer?

Comment: @MarioG I tried using $x_n=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $y_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$ and I got that $|x_n-y_n|\rightarrow 0$ but I also got that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\rightarrow 0$

Comment: That's because $\frac{1}{2n\pi} \to 0$. But if you take $x_n = \sqrt{n}$ and $y_n = \sqrt{n+1}$, what happens then?

Comment: @DanielFischer I tried it and got stuck because of the cosine function.

Comment: Presumably, you know a bit about Taylor expansions?

Comment: uniform continuity is defined on a set. Which set you considering to verifying?

Comment: @DanielFischer Well I do, but we can't use it because we "haven't learned" it in this course yet.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Because $\cos (1/\sqrt {n+1}) > \cos (1/\sqrt {n}),$ we have

$$(n+1)\cos (1/\sqrt {n+1}) - n\cos (1/\sqrt {n})$$ $$ > (n+1)\cos (1/\sqrt {n+1}) - n\cos (1/\sqrt {n+1}).$$